# How to store a multi dimensional array in a SQL database with Java?

Tags: java, sqlite, multidimensional-array

I have a java program that uses a two dimensional array (`double[][]`) to store pixel values of an image and I need to persist that information in a SQLite database. I can't for the love of me figure out how to serialize the `double[][]` array to store it in the database.

Anyone know how to do this?

PS: I know that storing something like a two dimensional array in a SQL database is not good practice but I need to for my use case.

Comment: When it comes to storing images in SQL databases, apparently something called blobs are used. Try looking into those.

Comment: @VarunGawande I'm not actually looking to store images in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) but you need to add Gson to your dependencies. Parse array to a string, store it in database as a string and convert it back to double 2D array when you need the array.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
double[][] multiDoubleArray = new double[][]{{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {4.0, 5.0, 6.0}};

// to string
String stringArray = gson.toJson(multiDoubleArray);   

// back to 2D array
double[][] multiDoubleArray2 = gson.fromJson(stringArray, double[][].class);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks!

Answer (score -3):

I would create a table with rowIndex, colIndex and value as the columns, where **rowIndex** and **colIndex** would be the **primary key**.

Here would be SQLite implementation:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE data(
    rowIndex INTEGER,
    colIndex INTEGER,
    val INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (rowIndex, colIndex)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index ON data (rowIndex, colIndex);

INSERT INTO data VALUES(rowIndex, colIndex, arr[rowIndex][colIndex]);
```

Now in your Java code, you would have to loop through the whole array and add one value by another.

Here I give you a sample method for adding a single pixel to the table:

```
public void addEntry(int rowIndex, int colIndex, double val) {
        if(rowIndex < 0 || colIndex < 0) return;

        String itemsSql = "INSERT INTO data(rowIndex, colIndex, val) VALUES(?,?,?)";

        Connection connection = getConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement itemsCmd = connection.prepareStatement(itemsSql);

            //Load 
            itemsCmd.setInt(1, rowIndex);
            itemsCmd.setInt(2, colIndex);
            itemsCmd.setDouble(3, val);

            //Execute 
            itemsCmd.executeUpdate();  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ErrorDialog.show(e);
        }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
double[][] values;
addEntry(0, 0, values[0][0]);
```

Or with little help of looping, you get indexes to do the job :)

Let me know if that helped :)

Comment: So basically @iHaveCodingIssues will only be able to store one image in that table. I doubt that is what is wanted.

Comment: Yes, as his question states, he just wants to store a single image's pixels into SQL database, my answer solves that

Comment: I dunno, he’ll have to clear that up, I’m still open to the possibility that there might be more double[][] objects that he might want to persist. If not, then go ahead, your answer works.

Comment: Hmmm. If he wanted more double[][] objects, then he could just easily create multiple tables in the database, that would still work like a charm.

Comment: You’ve assumed that the number of images are static.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is indeed as @VarunGawande said, I need to store the double array on one database row since I will be storing more of these arrays in the future. I should have mentioned this in my question, my bad.